# How to set up a basic Java EE Workspace with JSP forms and servlets in my particular setup?

Tags: workspace

I'm on extended medical leave from my job and practicing at setting up my own workspace at home without the assistance of workspace setup documentation. I know I need a web.xml file somewhere in this structure but I'm not sure where it goes in the Web Content.

I'm only looking to create an input text field to enter a number and the user receives a number back from the tomcat server, but I don't know the proper place to create the Servlet java file in this particular folder structure.

My project has the standard Java Resources, Javascript Resources, build, and WebContent directories so far.

I've tried to Google for a similar project setup but no Youtube or Google workspace tutorial has shown the same workspace setup that I have. Does anyone know of one?

Yours Truly
(As Humanly Possible)
cnight62

Comment: I found this great video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wty6OROO__8

Comment: Why not just use any IDE like IntelliJ to setup the files for you. If you are using maven then there are many archetype there from which you can choose.

Comment: Thanks Silverfang I will try IntelliJ.